# Amazon S3 beginners query

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I have a distributed system which consists of 2 applications **A** and **B**.
B calls a particular API of A for which an underlying workflow is executed during which a file a generated and uploaded onto `S3`. **A** does a client-side encryption to the file before uploading.The API response to **B** is the bucket+link location of the uploaded file.

Now at a later point in time **B** wishes to download the file from S3.

There are 2 ways of doing this -

1. implementing the download functionality at **B**'s end in which case it would need to know the AWS keys that **A** used to upload.
2. Have **A** expose a `download` functionality to **B** so that **B** would not need to have knowledge of the AWS keys that **A** uses to upload.

Option 2 seems like the correct way to go about doing things. 
Is my understanding correct or is there a third more reasonable approach ?

Comment: Based on the limited amount of information, you answered your own question already. Option 2, if A has something B needs, A should be the gatekeeper and expose only what it needs to. (data to give to provide to B, the client).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may wish to consider a "halfway house" using query string authentication.  Essentially, when B wants to download the file it makes a request to A asking for a download link.  A then generates a time-limited [pre-signed request URL](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth) which B can then use to download the file directly from S3.

As you've tagged your question "java" I'll assume you're using the AWS Java SDK, in which case the method you need is `generatePresignedUrl` in [AmazonS3Client](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html)